# Is it possible to using in elasticsearch spring data query IN like in MySQL?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need using query IN like in MySQL so my question is it "is possible" ? I try find something in googl`e but with out result. If it possible how I should do that ?

Maybe use clousure should? But how in elasticsearch spring data I should use?

My code:

TransactionIndexRepository:

```
public interface TransactionIndexRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<TransIndex, String> {

    List<TransIndex> findBySellerIn(String sellers);

}
```

TransactionQueryController:

```
@RestController
public class TransactionQueryController {


    private TransactionIndexRepository transactionIndexRepository;
    private TransactionService transactionService;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionQueryController(TransactionService transactionService) {
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/transaction/search", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private Map search(
            @RequestParam(value = "commentText", required = false) String commentText,
            @RequestParam(value = "commentType", required = false) Long commentType,
            @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
            @RequestParam(value = "priceFrom", required = false) Long priceFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "priceTo", required = false) Long priceTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "tsFrom", required = false) Long tsFrom,
            @RequestParam(value = "tsTo", required = false) Long tsTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "seller", required = false) Long seller,
            @RequestParam(value = "item", required = false) Long item,
            @RequestParam(value = "tree_cat", required = false) Long tree_cat,
            @RequestParam(value = "buyer", required = false) Long buyer,
            @RequestParam(value = "cat", required = false) Long cat,
            @RequestParam(value = "sellers", required = false) String sellers,
            Pageable pageable) {



        System.out.println(transactionIndexRepository.findBySellerIn(sellers));


        final TransIndexSearchParams searchParams = TransIndexSearchParams.builder()
                .commentText(commentText)
                .commentType(commentType)
                .title(title)
                .priceFrom(priceFrom)
                .priceTo(priceTo)
                .tsFrom(tsFrom)
                .tsTo(tsTo)
                .seller(seller)
                .item(item)
                .tree_cat(tree_cat)
                .buyer(buyer)
                .cat(cat)
                .build();

        return transactionService.searchByIndexParams(searchParams, pageable);
    }

}
```

And I`v got ERROR:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: May god forgive you for description of your question.

Comment: Please paste the full stack trace, i.e. what comes after "... with root cause".

Comment: rad11, are you there?

Answer (score 1):

In your repository class, you can simply define a `findByXyzIn()` [query method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.criterions) that takes a collection of strings, like this:

```
findByNameIn(Collection<String> names);
```

The equivalent DSL query that is going to be generated will look like this:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "field": {
              "name": "name1"
            }
          },
          {
            "field": {
              "name": "name2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you've created a `findBy..In()` method but now you hit an NPE. Do you have a stack trace?